# Xorg.conf (nvidia) Second Monitor getting settings of first

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

I've been spending the weekend (and some time before that) trying to set up my Korean QHD270 and Benq G2222HDL monitors with Ubuntu 13.10.

With the nouveau drivers install *both* monitor function perfectly fine. After installing the nvidia drivers the Benq *works* but the QHD270 does not.

Now, after days of struggling I managed to get the QHD270 to work following a mixture of blogs, particularly; [this one](http://www.overclock.net/a/sound-quieter-in-linux-than-windows-2560x1440-27-korean-display-not-working-the-problems-i-encountered-and-their-solution) and [learnitwithme](http://learnitwithme.com/?p=342). Now, unfortunatly my G2222HDL does not work. I fixed the QHD270 by supplying a custom EDID, my xorg.conf looks like so (excluding keyboard and mouse):

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen  "Default Screen" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
     Identifier "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Configured Video Device"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    Option "CustomEDID" "DFP:/etc/X11/edid-shimian.bin"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Default Screen"
    Device "Configured Video Device"
    Monitor "Configured Monitor"
EndSection
```

Now, I tried defining a new `Device`,`Monitor` and `Screen` then in `ServerLayout` adding `Screen "Second Screen" RightOf "Default Screen"`, but after doing so neither monitor worked.

Hoping to fix the issue using a GUI based tool I opened up NVIDIA X Server Settings, which shows my current layout as:

[image]

It seems that something is being output to the monitor, as suggested by my print screen:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5120 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440      60.0*+
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected 2560x1440+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440      60.0*+
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And an extract from my log file (perhaps this is relevant?)

```
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GeForce GTX 680 at PCI:2:0:0
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0):     ACB QHD270 (DFP-0) (boot, connected)
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-3
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-4
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0): ACB QHD270 (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0): ACB QHD270 (DFP-0): Internal Dual Link TMDS
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-1: Internal Single Link TMDS
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-2: Internal Single Link TMDS
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-3: Internal Single Link TMDS
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-4: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.862] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
```

Comment: Have you tried the Ubuntu 'Displays' tool? Messing with the X.org configuration for this is a huge pain. I am successfully using two monitors with the nvidia drivers all set up with 'Displays'. Also, nvidia settings report the same monitor (ACB QHD270). You have likely configured something wrong.

Comment: @errikos The Ubuntu screen display shows a similar situation to the nvidia one. There are two identical screens (the QHD270)

Comment: @HennyH what is the output of `xrandr`?  Have you checked your log file in search of anything useful?

Comment: @fboaventura I've added the output of xrandr, I didn't see anything useful in my log file, but I added the part I think lists the found displays.

Comment: @HennyH removing the configuration you made on your `xorg.conf` does both monitors get recognized by `xorg`?  If yes, then what is the output of `xrandr`?

Comment: Well, xrandr does not cooperate well with the nvidia drivers. I suggest removing your xorg configuration, running `sudo nvidia xconfig` and try setting up the monitors from "Displays". Regards.

Comment: @errikos I tried that for ages, there is no way that I know of to configure my QHD270 without using a custom EDID.

Comment: @HennyH What I am talking about is the placement, not EDID. You can still specify a custom EDID after running `sudo nvidia-xconfig`, but let "Displays" manage the monitor placement and output. I am suggesting this because myself too have been messing around with the Nvidia drivers and this always worked. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You may try using the following `xorg.conf`.  It configures two `Screen` and a `ServerLayout` section to manage them.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia0"
    Driver     "nvidia"
    Option     "CustomEDID" "DFP:/etc/X11/edid-shimian.bin"
    Option      "RenderAccel"              "true"
    Option      "UseEdidFreqs"             "true"
    Option      "MetaModes"     "2055x1440,1920x1080;1366x768,1366x768;1024x768,1024x768"
    Screen     0
    BusID      PCI:2:0:0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia1"
    Driver     "nvidia"
    Option      "RenderAccel"              "true"
    Option      "UseEdidFreqs"             "true"
    Option      "MetaModes"     "2055x1440,1920x1080;1366x768,1366x768;1024x768,1024x768"
    Screen     1
    BusID      PCI:2:0:0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor0"
    Option     "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor1"
    Option     "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "nvidia0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth  24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth      24
        Modes      "2055x1440" "1920x1080" "1366x768" "1024x768" 
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "nvidia1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth  24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth      24
        Modes      "2055x1440" "1920x1080" "1366x768" "1024x768" 
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "ServerLayout0"
    Screen     0 "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen     1 "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice "Generic Keyboard" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice "Configured Mouse" "CorePointer"
    Option     "Xinerama"
EndSection
```

I may be missing something, so you will have to test this out.  I used the confs from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XineramaHowTo) as reference.

Another approach you may try is configuring your monitors manually, using `xrandr`.  You will have to configure another `Monitor` section and even the second `Device` section without the `EDID`, nonetheless.  But the command line would be:

```
$ xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --primary --mode 2560x1440 --output DVI-D-0 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of DVI-I-1
```

or even in multiple lines as:

```
$ xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --primary --mode 2560x1440
$ xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of DVI-I-1
```

EDIT: Added `MetaModes` to `Device` section, and `SubSection` with modes to `Screen` section.

Comment: @fboventura I just tried using that config file, it had the same result as the one I tried. After rebooting the QHD270 did not work but the Benq did but it displays a 'Running in low graphics mode, configuration settings could not be determined' or something like that. Also with the xrandr it says `xrandr: cannot find mode 1920x1080`

Comment: @HennyH just the `xrandr` throws something different? And, are the monitors plugged on the proper DVI ports?  I assumed your Benq is plugged on the second port `DVI-D-0`.  You may try switching them.

Comment: @fboventura I checked using randr and the Benq (non-primary) is on `DVI-D-0`, because the primary is on `DVI-I-1` which I suppose the one I'm currently using.

Comment: @HennyH changed some configurations.  But, the suggestion from errikos above is valid.

Comment: I just gave that new xorg.conf a go, had the same issuse as with the last version :(. I've looked into using the display settings to configure the monitors but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @HennyH there are some files you may check: `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and `~/.config/monitors.xml`.  The last may be removed, and it will be recreated at the next `X` restart.  Lookig at the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file may also tell which devices, drivers, monitors `Xorg` is detecting, if you wish you may paste your log on some pastebin.  Another alternative is to remove the actual `Xorg.conf` and, from your started X, run `sudo X :2 -configure` and take a look on what is being detected and make adjusts.